# Sorting a list of tuples with 3 elements in python

Tags: python, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of some tuples. Each tuple has three elements. I need to sort the list. To break tie between two tuples, first element of tuple is looked then if still tied then the second element. List is like below.

```
L = [(1, 14, 0), (14, 1, 1), (1, 14, 2), (14, 2, 3), (2, 4, 4), (4, 11, 5), (11, -1000, 6)]
```

In C the sort function takes a compare function and that does everything simply. But I couldn't figure it out after trying for sometimes in `python`. Can anybody help me?

Comment: `sorted(L)` gives me `[(1, 14, 0), (1, 14, 2), (2, 4, 4), (4, 11, 5), (11, -1000, 6), (14, 1, 1), (14, 2, 3)]`. Is it a desired output?

Comment: The order you want is called lexicographic order, and it's the default ordering for sequences, so you don't have to do anything special.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Just sort the list; the default sort does just what you want.

When comparing two tuples, they are ordered according to their contents; sorted on the first element first, then if they are equal, sorted on the second element, etc.

Demo:

```
>>> L = [(14, 2, 3), (1, 14, 0), (14, 1, 1), (1, 14, 2), (2, 4, 4), (4, 11, 5), (11, -1000, 6)]
>>> sorted(L)
[(1, 14, 0), (1, 14, 2), (2, 4, 4), (4, 11, 5), (11, -1000, 6), (14, 1, 1), (14, 2, 3)]
```

I moved the `(14, 2, 3)` element forward to show that it is still sorted after `(14, 1, 1)`.

Python's `list.sort()` method and `sorted()` function take a `key` function that returns a value on which to sort instead if you need a different sort order. If you wanted to sort on the last element first, then second last, etc. for example, you'd use:

```
sorted(L, key=lambda t: t[::-1])
```

where the lambda returns a reversed tuple to sort on instead. The callable object you pass to `key` is called for each element in the input sequence to 'augment' the list before sorting, as if you had done:

```
[s[1] for s in sorted((key(s), s) for s in L)]
```

The `t[::-1]` uses a [reversing slice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/the-python-slice-notation).

For more detail, see the [Python Sorting HOWTO](http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting/).

Comment: I couldn't understand following part.
sorted(L, key=lambda t: t[::-1])
Would you please explain a bit?

Comment: I previously tried in different way. Code snipet is here: http://paste.ubuntu.com/6013339/ But it was not working correctly. Where did I do wrong?

Comment: You defined `cmp_to_key()` twice, nested. The outer function doesn't return anything, so the result of that function is that you sort by `None` for each value; that leaves the original order unaffected.

Comment: Remove the other function altogether.

Comment: Ohh, My mistake. I just copied and pasted from net and pasted it mistakenly inside a function. :-P It is working now.